# Split PHP Array by Key=>Value

Tags: php, arrays

I have a two dimensional array like this:

```
$array = [
    [..., "key"=>"key 1",...],
    [..., "key"=>"key 2",...],
    [..., "key"=>"key 2",...],
    [..., "key"=>"key 3",...],
    [..., "key"=>"key 3",...],
    [..., "key"=>"key 3",...],
];
```

I want a three dimensional array from this array, splitted by the same "key" value,
like this:

```
$array_output = [
    [
        [..., "key"=>"key 1",...],
    ],
    [
        [..., "key"=>"key 2",...],
        [..., "key"=>"key 2",...],
    ],
    [
        [..., "key"=>"key 3",...],
        [..., "key"=>"key 3",...],
        [..., "key"=>"key 3",...],
    ],
];
```

Comment: Use `array_chunk($array,1)`.

Comment: I would have gone with `array_reduce`

Comment: @AlivetoDie this is not a duplicate of that question. That is a simple split into equal size chunks, this is splitting based on values of a certain key in the array.

Comment: yes @Nick, you're  is right, this is the very same thing what I want :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with [array-reduce](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php). Consider this example:

```
$arr = [];
$arr[] = array("key" => "key1", "v" => "a");
$arr[] = array("key" => "key2", "v" => "b");
$arr[] = array("key" => "key3", "v" => "c");
$arr[] = array("key" => "key2", "v" => "d");
$arr[] = array("key" => "key2", "v" => "e");

function reduceByKey($carry, $item) {
    $carry[$item["key"]][] = $item;
    return $carry;
}
$res = array_values(array_reduce($arr, "reduceByKey",[]));
```

Now `$res` will have your output. Notice that the order of the keys in `$arr` in not relevant.

Answer (score 0):

**Finally, This function fulfilled my expectation:**

```
function _group_by($array, $key) {
    $return = array();
    foreach($array as $val) {
        $return[$val->$key][] = $val;
    }
    return $return;
}
$array = _group_by($array, 'key');
```

However, this returns with Key Value pair, like:

```
[
    "key 1"=>[
        [..., "key"=>"key 1",...],
    ],
    "key 2"=>[
        [..., "key"=>"key 2",...],
        [..., "key"=>"key 2",...],
    ],
    "key 3"=>[
        [..., "key"=>"key 3",...],
        [..., "key"=>"key 3",...],
        [..., "key"=>"key 3",...],
    ],
];
```

but that cause no problem for me :)

Comment: After `$array = _group_by($array, 'key');`, do `$array = array_values($array);`. this will re-index your array to your desired format