# Multidimensional array extract equal column values

Tags: php, arrays, element

I have the following array

```
  array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["cart_id"]=>
    string(6) "269984"
    ["customer_id"]=>
    string(5) "55152"
    ["product_id"]=>
    string(4) "2323"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["cart_id"]=>
    string(6) "269985"
    ["customer_id"]=>
    string(5) "55152"
    ["product_id"]=>
    string(3) "730"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["cart_id"]=>
    string(6) "269986"
    ["customer_id"]=>
    string(5) "66666"
    ["product_id"]=>
    string(4) "7297"
  }
}
```

AS you can see the first 2 elements are with equal customer_id values. I want extract all equal or not column values in a new array, which will look like that:

```
  array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["cart_id"]=>
      int(269984)
      ["customer_id"]=>
      int(55152)
      ["product_id"]=>
      int(2323)
    }
    [1]=>
    array(3) {
      ["cart_id"]=>
      int(269985)
      ["customer_id"]=>
      int(55152)
      ["product_id"]=>
      int(730)
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["cart_id"]=>
      int(269986)
      ["customer_id"]=>
      int(66666)
      ["product_id"]=>
      int(7297)
    }
  }
}
```

Is this possible via some php functions ? Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split PHP Array by Key=>Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54688599/split-php-array-by-key-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No build in function to do exactly that. This is the logic:

```
$initialArray = [/** your data  **/];
$newArray = [];

foreach ($initialArray as $item) {
    $newArray[$item['customer_id']][] = $item;
}

$newArray = array_values($newArray);
```

First you make a new array indexed by the customer ID which contains all elements for that customer. Then (optionally) if you want it to be numerically indexed you use `array_values` to clear the customer id array indexes.

Comment: I've tried your scenario but 1 of the elements is missing. And it start working when i added $tempCartsArray[$cart['customer_id']][$key] = $cart;

Comment: I don't see a reason for an element to be missing, please provide me some example somewhere where it's not working.

Comment: @RumenPanchev, this approach looks sound to me.  Edit your question with `var_export`s of your sample data.  (https://3v4l.org/80ZqC)